# .plot(y=) gives the same chart despite changing the values of y

Tags: python, r, anaconda, jupyter

I have pulled the details of the company named "BBRY" and saved it in a variable `bb`. The dataframe comprises of the following elements:

```
                   Close     High      Low     Open    Volume
Symbol Date                                                    
BBRY   2007-07-02  71.4200  71.8000  66.3567  67.3233  56422755
       2007-07-03  69.3133  72.2967  68.8000  69.3867  26506620
       2007-07-04  69.3133  72.2967  68.8000  69.3867         0
```

When I execute `bb.plot(y=Close)`, and `bb.plot(y="Open")`, both of their graphs are similar. 
I have tried doing this multiple times for different but without any avail.
How do i get .plot() to show different graphs for different values of `y` 
[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas_datareader import data 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
company = "BBRY"
start = "2007-07-01"
end = "2008-12-31"
bb = data.get_data_morningstar(company,start, end)

bb.head(3)

bb["Close"].plot()
bb["Open"].plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

Those plots are **not** identical. You are plotting open/close prices of a stock. They are very similar - but not identical:

[image]

You can see this if you overlay them - I used gimp for that, coloring one black and using a partially overlay.

Open/Close prises for the same stock will vary a little, but not much - and you are dealing with about 20 $ (?) per cm resolution. Unless your stock crashes you won't see wildly different plots.